# Round off Issue with Decimal

Tags: sql, decimal

```
SELECT CAST(960 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) -- it gives 960.00 
SELECT CAST(178.5 AS NUMERIC(18,2)) -- it gives 178.50
```

I need the result 960 and 178.5, how could I do that

Comment: I did this as SELECT CAST(178 AS float) -- it gives 178

Comment: This is a presentation issue. How are you displaying the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below

```
SELECT CAST(960 AS NUMERIC(18,0)) -- it will give 960

SELECT CAST(178.5 AS NUMERIC(18,1)) -- it will give 178.5
```